# Why ReleaseDC()?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm developing MFC app and I at some point I got some weird Access Violation errors during idle processing loop.

After some research I discovered that might have been caused by unreleased DCs. I have called ReleaseDC() function after every GetDC() call and errors stopped to appearing.

**What I can't understand is why do I have to call ReleaseDC()?** 
. For example:

```
void CMainFrame::OnUpdateStatusLODLevel(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable();

    RenderingStatistics Stats = theApp.xAM->GetRenderingStatistics();

    std::wstring wsText;

    wsText = L"LOD: ";
    wsText += std::to_wstring(Stats.uiCurrentLOD);

    pCmdUI->SetText(wsText.c_str());

    CDC* dc = m_wndStatusBar.GetDC();

    if (dc){
        CSize size = dc->GetTextExtent(wsText.c_str());
        m_wndStatusBar.SetPaneWidth(m_wndStatusBar.CommandToIndex(ID_STATUS_BAR_LOD_LEVEL), size.cx);

        ReleaseDC(dc); // without this call Access Violation errors appears
    }
}
```

Comment: If you take a DC, you should give it back when you're done. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Resources on a computer are not infinite, that includes things such as handles, device-contexts, files etc. If you just keep on allocating resource and not releasing them, the system will sooner or later run out of that resource.

Comment: You have to know and follow the protocol of windows programming strictly (MFC is no real benefit, just a wrapper avoiding some boilerplate)

Comment: Maby I'm wrong but when I call GetDC() I always think I'm getting a pointer to a DC that is owned by specific a resource. In that case it shouldn't be my responsibility to release it in any way, but quite the oposite - it may cause this resource to stop working.

Comment: I'll go for the simple answer: Because that's what [**the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71eseab0.aspx) *says* you must do. Do you need a better reason than that?

Answer (score 2):

**chris** said:

> If you take a DC, you should give it back when you're done. It's as
>   simple as that.

And he/she is right.

**Some programmer dude** said:

> Resources on a computer are not infinite, that includes things such as
>   handles, device-contexts, files etc. If you just keep on allocating
>   resource and not releasing them, the system will sooner or later run
>   out of that resource.

And he/she is also right too.

You should listen to them.

Other applications and processes, even other threads in current process and application, won't be able to retrieve the device context of the window neither with `GetDC` nor `GetWindowDC` until your application invokes/calls `ReleaseDC`.

Comment: Probably the confusion is because the function is named *GetDC*, not something more suggestive, like OpenDC, AquireDC, etc. I mean the function name doesn't hint to the fact that the resource needs freeing. To make it more confusing, you don't have to free the handle returned by GetSafeHDC, for instance...